# Solving "time evolution" partial differential eq using Lagrange shift operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, functional-equations, operator-algebras, semigroup-of-operators

I was reading about the [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform) $(W[\cdot])$, and how it's related to the difussion equation in one dimension. It's relation is given by that $W[f]$ is the convolution with the [Heat kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel) at $t=1$, and the general solution is given by the generalized Weierstrass transform $W_t[\cdot]$ as the exponential of $t\partial^2_x$. If someone applied $W_t[]$, it should satisfy the difussion equation according to the first source:

$$W_t[f](x)=\exp\left(t{\partial^2\over\partial x^2}\right)[f]$$

$$\Rightarrow {\partial\over\partial t}f= {\partial^2\over\partial x^2}f$$

$$\Rightarrow {\partial\over\partial t}W_t[f](x)= {\partial^2\over\partial x^2}W_t[f](x)$$

Given that $W_t[\cdot]$ evolve the initial function $f_0(x)=f(x,t)$ in time, and because of its exponential form, it seems to me that is just the [Lagrange Shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) acting in the time domain. My way of justify the property of $W_t[\cdot]$ as a time evolution operator would be the following.

1. Write the shift operator acting on time by a displacement $\tau$, in exponential form.
2. Replace $\partial_t$ by the relation given in the difussion equation, meaning $\partial_t=\partial^2_x$.
3. Check if it commutes with every operator in the equation.

If we write the shift operator $T_\tau[\cdot]$:

$$T_\tau[f]=\exp\left(\tau{\partial\over\partial t}\right)=\exp\left(\tau{\partial^2\over\partial x^2}\right)$$

Then if $[\cdot,\cdot]$ its the commutator bracket, then $[T_\tau,\partial_t]=[T_\tau,\partial_x]=0$, because of [symmetry of second deerivatives](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#In_Lie_theory), and because [polynomial of the same operator commute with each other](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20968/rules-for-operator-commutativity). So its clear that $T_\tau$ satisfy the diffusion eq.

Now, I have to questions with this. The first is, given that $\tau$ is dummy variable and $t$ is a real variable of the problem, Is it my approach correct?

Second, Can we construct a solutions of any PDE of the form $\partial_t f=L[f]$, where $L$ is a linear operator only dependent of $x$, by applying $T_\tau[\cdot]$ to $f$, and setting $t=0$ to do a functional equation?

To give an example of how to solve this way, I'd solve the one-way wave equation:

$${\partial\over\partial t}f = \pm {\partial\over\partial x}f$$

Writing the time shift $T_\tau$:

$$T_\tau[f]=\exp\left(\tau{\partial\over\partial t}\right)=\exp\left(\pm\tau{\partial\over\partial x}\right)$$

Then applying to the equation:

$${\partial\over\partial t}\exp\left(\tau{\partial\over\partial t}\right)[f] = \pm {\partial\over\partial x}\exp\left(\pm\tau{\partial\over\partial x}\right)[f]$$

$${\partial\over\partial t}f(x,t+\tau)=\pm{\partial\over\partial x}f(x\pm\tau,t) $$

Setting $t=0$, then we have:

$$f(x,\tau)=f(x\pm\tau,0)=f_0(x\pm\tau) $$

Then replacing $\tau$ for $t$ gives the correct solution. This also works for $\partial_t f=x\partial_x f$, to give anothe example.